# Saving eloquent model instance which does not have an id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I tried to use an action (button click) to save a new instance of an eloquent model - and always got a `404` response.

Digging around in the livewire code, I found that the following method is throwing the `404` ...

```
    /**
     * Restore the model from the model identifier instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Database\ModelIdentifier  $value
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
     */
    public function restoreModel($value)
    {
        return $this->getQueryForModelRestoration(
            (new $value->class)->setConnection($value->connection), $value->id
        )->useWritePdo()->firstOrFail()->load($value->relations ?? []);
    }
```

... which makes sense - `firstOrFail()` without an `id`.

What would be the right approach in such a scenario?

btw. am I the only one who dislikes `firstOrFail()` / `findOrFail` - it is so hard to figure out where those `404` are coming from ...

Comment: The point of firstOrFail and findOrFail is that they fail with a 404 when the item is not found. If you don't want it to throw an exception, use first() or find() instead, which return null when the model is not found.

Comment: I think we need to see the rest of your code before we can help to answer this question.

Comment: @Kurucu thanks for your comment. However, the `restoreModel` method is in class `Illuminate\Queue\SerializesAndRestoresModelIdentifiers` called by a Livewire Middleware method `Livewire\HydrationMiddleware\Livewire\HydrationMiddleware->hydrate`. So it is more an issue with how Livewire hydrates the model than with my code. I would need need some way to override the hydration I guess ...

Comment: Have you considered using `->firstOrCreate()`?